# Some kind of IF condition in INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next tables:

```
   table1               table2
id. value position    id   state
                       1.  false
```

What I need is to insert data in to table1 if state from table2 is true.
Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table1(value, position)
VALUES('someVal', 3)
IF table2.id = 1 AND table2.state = true
```

Comment: Is the data you want to insert form a table3? Also is it for a one shot or something that will be part of a larger process and can be reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `exists`?

```
INSERT INTO table1(value, position)
    SELECT v.value, v.position
    FROM (VALUES('someVal', 3)) v(value, position)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE t2.id = 1 AND t2.state = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select only item where table2.State = true before inserting

If you have your data comming from another table it would look like this

```
INSERT INTO table1(value, position)
SELECT ValueId, Value 
FROM TableValue
INNER JOIN Table2
ON TableValue.ValueID = Table2.ID
WHERE table2.state = true
```